# Getting current URL using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am very new in javascript and jquery.

```
$.getJSON("idcheck.php?callback=?", { url:  /*i want full url to be print*/ }, function(json){
  //alert(json.message);
});
```

How do i get current full url on page on after url: in above?

Thank you

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/how-to-extract-current-url-in-jquery.

Comment: I already seen it but i don't know how to implement it in my context, so any help would be greatful

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This will give you the current url:

```
window.location.pathname
```

edit:

```
$.getJSON("idcheck.php?callback=?", { url:  window.location.pathname }, function(json){
  //alert(json.message);
});
```

edit 2: Using PHP (found [via](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/get_current_page_url.php))

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
?>


$.getJSON("idcheck.php?callback=?", { url:  "<?php echo curPageURL(); ?>" }, function(json){
  //alert(json.message);
});
```

Comment: How do i implement in it? Currently when i put this, it just shows as window.location.pathname;

Comment: it shows as url:  window.location.pathname, not the current url of it, i need something like url : localhost/index.html

Comment: yes, that's the point. When it will be called it will use the correct url. If you want it to show in the source code of your page, use a backend language and not javascript

Comment: I added an example to my answer

Comment: Ah i see, sorry for the trouble caused.

Comment: note, this `pathname` only returns the path and will not include any query parameters present in the current url.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `window.location.pathname` or `window.location`

Answer (score 3):

To get current page URL via Jquery and Javascript

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      //jquery
    $(location).attr('href');

    //pure javascript
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;

    // to show it in an alert window
    alert(window.location);
});


$.getJSON("idcheck.php?callback=?", { url:$(location).attr('href')}, function(json){
  //alert(json.message);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
var path = window.location.pathname; // path only
var url      = window.location.href;     // full URL
```

Edit:

```
$.getJSON("idcheck.php?callback=?", { url: window.location.href }, function(json){ alert(json.message);});
```