# get full url form server

Tags: javascript, php, url, server

I want to get the URL form server side.

I'm using that request to call ajax to server:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "includes/pages_includes/func_infos.php",
  data: {
    "...."         : "..."
  },
  beforeSend: function() {

  },
  success: function(data) {

  }
});
```

If I use **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']**(In func_infos.php) to get URL  It gives me: **includes/pages_includes/func_infos.php**.

I want to get as URL: **http://localhost/insc/web_/view_page.php?id_page=10**.

How can I get the needed URL?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802954/getting-current-url-using-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Use this approach for javascript:

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

For PHP:

```
<?php 
// Program to display URL of current page. 

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on') 
    $link = "https"; 
else
    $link = "http"; 

// Here append the common URL characters. 
$link .= "://"; 

// Append the host(domain name, ip) to the URL. 
$link .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 

// Append the requested resource location to the URL 
$link .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 

// Print the link 
echo $link; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to current full url using php

```
$pageURL = 'http';
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {
    $pageURL .= "s";
}
$pageURL .= "://";
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
} else {
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
```

Refernce link : http://webcheatsheet.com/PHP/get_current_page_url.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get full url or your server supports both http or https then try

```
$link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```